# Let $D$ be an integral domain with $a , a', b,b' \in D$ where $a\sim a'$ and $b\sim b'$ Show that $a|b \iff a'|b'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I understand the definition of an integral domain to be a commutative ring with identity and no zero divisors. I also understand the definition of the equivalence relation. But I cant see how to use those two pieces of information together to prove this statement. 
After some digging I found the relation to be defined as: $a \sim a'$ $\iff a = a' u$ where $ u\in U(D)$ The units of D.

Comment: Does $\sim$ denote an equivalence relation on $D$? If so, then what relation? The statement is certainly not true for every equivalence relation on $D$.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean this specific equivalence relation? $$x\sim y\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}\exists\alpha\in D^*\ x=\alpha y$$

Comment: After some digging I found the relation to be defined as: $a \sim a'$ $\iff a = a' u$ where $ u\in U(D)$ The units of D.

Answer (score 2):

So I will assume we are using the equivalence relation $a \sim b$ iff $\exists \alpha \in D^\ast: x = \alpha y$, as suggested by Sassatelli.

Knowing $a \sim a'$ gives us $\alpha \in D^\ast$ with $a = \alpha a'$.

Knowing $b \sim b'$ given us $\alpha' \in D^\ast$ with $b = \alpha' b'$.

Assume $a | b$, so there exists some $k \in D$ with $b = ka$.

So $b' = (\alpha')^{-1} b = (\alpha')^{-1} k a = (\alpha')^{-1} k \alpha a'$. Here the inverse of $\alpha'$ exists as $\alpha' \in D^\ast$.

Hence $b' = k'a'$ for $k' = (\alpha')^{-1} k \alpha \in D$, so $a'|b'$.

Now the reverse implication is quite similar and left as an exercise..